# textbox text changes, querystring parameter doesn't

Tags: c#, asp.net, caching, querystringparameter

I'm using a Textbox with an AutoCompleteExtender.

Enter the part number, click Find - it fills in the page.
I have a button on the page that reads the text of the textbox, uses that as a querystring parameter, and opens a new window.

Works great the first time.  BUT
I close the 2nd window. 
Add a new part number, click Find - it fills in the page with the new information correctly.

I click the button - and here's the PROBLEM - 
It's holding the original part number when it opens the new window.

I've tried adding a second querystring parameter (datetime), and it still holds that same part number.  I've also tried transferring the text to a hidden label, and reading it from there (thinking the autocompleteextender had something to do with it). No luck.

Here's the code for the button -

```
protected void btnViewIncidents_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        try
        {
            string strDOT = txtXingList.Text;
            DateTime DT = DateTime.Now;
            btnViewIncidents.Attributes.Add("onclick","window.open('Incidents.aspx?DOT=" + strDOT + "&DT=" + DT + "'); return false;");
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            throw (ex);
        }
    }
```

and the code for the 2nd page retrieval of the parameters

```
string Crossing = Page.Request.QueryString["DOT"];
        string DT = Page.Request.QueryString["DT"];
        txtXingList.Text = Crossing;
```

Any suggestions/help is greatly appreciated!  Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Is the txtXingList being populated somewhere else? If it does, check the code, it might be called before the button click event.

Some event are called before the button click.

Since your form is surely a method="post", then when you click the btnviewIncidents the query string will not change.
If the page load uses the query string to populate the txtXingList then when the button event will be called it will contain the wrong value.

Comment: I put a break in the method, and noticed that the 2nd time around, it didn't break - just opened the page with the old part number.

Comment: Did you put break point everywhere you change the value of txtXingList.Text ?

Comment: yes. I stepped through the routine, and the method is picking up the new strDOT. However, when it does the actual open.window, its re-using the old strDOT. Wondering if it has something to do with ajax.  Also, I'm using firefox for testing.

Answer (score 0):

The page needed to know absolutely that you wanted a popup form, even though it just opens a new tab. Worked like a charm.

```
        try
        {
            string strDOT = txtXingList.Text;
            DateTime DT = DateTime.Now;

            string newWin = "window.open('../Application/AppsSB.aspx?DOT=" + strDOT + "&DT=" + DT + "');";

            ClientScript.RegisterStartupScript
             (this.GetType(), "pop", newWin, true);
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            throw (ex);
        }
```